# Paytm Integration only with Android App without Web Support

Tags: android, paytm

Can I integrate the paytm payment option  in Android Application without using the Server using the sandBox credentials 
here is  my sandbox credentials 
Sandbox Merchant ID       xxxxxxxxx
App Url                  www.abc.com
Sandbox Merchant  Key    xxxxxxxxxx
Channel Id                WAP
Industry Type                  Retail

Answer (score 1):

> Can I integrate the paytm payment option in Android Application
>   without using the Server

No, you cannot. the reason is that the checksum utility is only provided to servers. you cannot generate checksum solemnly using a Android device.

That being said, a relative simple approach you can take to test your solution is to use Java checksum utility paytm provides, it can be used with JAVA project in Android studio to generate checksum manually.